# Cycling through some checkboxes on my excel page

Tags: vba

I am VERY new to VBA (and know of it only within excel).

I am trying to cycle through some (but not all) checkboxes.  They are currently named CheckBox1 through CheckBox15.  Howe do I cycle through say for instance CheckBox5 through CheckBox10?

I guess I am hoping there is a 'method' similar to 'CheckType' for controls that will allow me to check name?

Here is what I have tried.  Causes a Compile Error - Sub or Function not defined, and highlights Worksheet.

```
Private Sub BoxCheck()
atLeastOneChecked = False
    For i = 2 To 4
        If Worksheets("ActiveX").Controls("Checkbox" & i).Value = True Then
            atLeastOneChecked = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

While the above doesnt work, what is below does:

```
Private Sub BoxCheck()
    atLeastOneChecked = False

    For i = 1 To 2
       If Sheet2.CheckBox2.Value = True Then
                atLeastOneChecked = True
       End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Of course, the loop has no affect on the outcome, but it compiles and atLeastOneChecked turns from False to True when Checkbox2 is True.  Note that Sheet2 has been named ActiveX.  I clearly don't understand how Worksheet and Controls work.  Could someone help?

After fixing the error described below, this still won't work.  I simplified to the following:

```
Private Sub BoxCheck()
    Dim ole As OLEObject

    atLeastOneChecked = False
    Set ole = Sheets("ActiveX").OLEObjects("Checkbox2")
    If ole.Value = True Then
        atLeastOneChecked = True
    End If
 End Sub
```

This doesn't work.  It fails at:

```
If ole.Value = True Then
```

The error states:  Object Doesn't support this property or method

This is true for OLEObjects, but not for Checkboxes.  When I look at the properties of ole, I see that its Object property is set to Object/Checkbox and that this Object has a value.  I guess that is what I should be referencing in my if statement, but I don't know how.

Comment: One error you're having is that you are using `Worksheet` when you should be using `Worksheets`. To catch this earlier, type `Option Explicit` at the top of your module.

Comment: Thanks - changed that but it still doesn't work. I know why, but I don't know the solution to the problem.  The problem is that Worksheet doesn't have a "Controls" member. It has OLEobjects and Shapes, but I cannot seem to get that to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved the problem.

The value of the Checkbox is accessed by Referencing the Object property within the OLEObject I set...Like this:

```
If ole.Object.Value = True Then
```

Thanks for all your help.  If someone has a more elegant solution, I would still like to see it.

Comment: Ahh, good one.  The `ole.Value = True` didn't throw any errors for me, but since this works for you, it's the best answer.  :-)

Comment: Thx, this was the trick for me as well. If (wsActions.OLEObjects("chkOpt1").Object.Value) Then doit(1) Else doit(0) /
wsActions.OLEObjects("chkOpt1").Object.Value = False

Answer (score 0):

Use `CheckBox.Name`

Example:

```
For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes 
    If cb.Name = "CheckBox5"
        ' Do stuff
    End If
Next cb
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [@Parker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13403730/493055)'s answer:

```
Private Sub BoxCheck()
    atleastonechecked = False
    Dim oles As OLEObject
    For i = 2 To 4
        'If you're using Shapes Controls:
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ActiveX").Shapes("Check Box " & i).Value = True Then
            atleastonechecked = True
        End If
        ' If you're using ActiveX Controls
        Set oles = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ActiveX").OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i)
        If oles.Value = True Then
            atleastonechecked = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Sorry, just put together the previous answer without testing - that always fails.  Just use the `If` loop based on what type of control you're using.

Comment: When I try this, I get an error...it isn't recognizing the Worksheet. I have edited my original question to include what I tried

Comment: This still isn't working for me. I am confuesd about the error - 'Object doesn't support this method or property' which when I debug takes place at the line     If ole.Value = True Then    When I check the properties of ole, I see that it is a OLEObject/CheckBox and that in the Object Property, it does have a value?