# Using a loop to enable checkboxes in excel

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I am currently working on an Excel spreadsheet and could use some help looping through checkboxes. What I am trying to do is when one Box is checked another group of boxes become visible and enabled. Any advice on how to do this would be most appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Always helps to post your current ode, and explain exactly what's going wrong when it runs.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have code currently. What I had would work, but it was sloppy and looked like garbage. I was manually having the values changed. I guess a better question for me to ask would be is there a way i can format a loop.

Comment: kinda like i = integer 

for i <= 10

  CheckBox"i".enable = true
  CheckBox"i". visible = true
  i++

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403635/cycling-through-some-checkboxes-on-my-excel-page

Comment: Thank you for your help. Looks very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your checkboxes are form controls located on `Sheet 1`, you can build a collection of all the checkboxes that need to be enabled when `checkBox1` is clicked and do the following:

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()
Dim cb1 As checkBox
Dim cb2 As checkBox
Dim cb3 As checkBox
Dim cb As checkBox
Dim cbCollection As New Collection
Set cb1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CheckBoxes("Check Box 1")
Set cb2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CheckBoxes("Check Box 2")
Set cb3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CheckBoxes("Check Box 3")
cbCollection.Add cb2
cbCollection.Add cb3
If cb1.Value = 1 Then
    For Each cb In cbCollection
        cb.Enabled = True
        cb.Visible = True
    Next cb
Else
    For Each cb In cbCollection
        cb.Enabled = False
        cb.Visible = False
    Next cb
End If
End Sub
```